# How to find out which process is hogging the linux server?

Tags: linux, performance

We have a RHEL server. Today it suddenly became slow. Symptoms - It was responding slow to ping queries from other server. When I try to login using ssh, it was taking about 10 seconds to login. I was able to resolve the problem by doing some guess work. I killed one process which I thought was culprit. Which resolved the problem. Though I would like to know what's proper approach to detect the culprit in such kind of "slow server" situations. Le me know proper way to resolving such slowness issues and decting the process causing the slowness.

These were the conditions when the server was slow -

```
# vmstat 3 3
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  1    176 6730868 285052 4899676    0    0     3     4    0    0  1  1 97  1  0
 0  0    176 6751576 285064 4899704    0    0     0   115 15307 37171  1  1 96  3  0
 0  0    176 6751948 285068 4899700    0    0     0    23 14813 39559  1  1 98  1  0

# top

top - 16:38:18 up 150 days, 19:36, 64 users,  load average: 1.68, 1.46, 1.44
Tasks: 1287 total,   2 running, 1284 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.3%us,  1.7%sy,  0.1%ni, 95.9%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16620824k total,  9867124k used,  6753700k free,   287424k buffers
Swap:  8193140k total,      176k used,  8192964k free,  4898996k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
26258 khk       34  19  130m  47m 7088 S 11.2  0.3 385:32.42 edm
```

Though I would like to know what's proper approach to detect the culprit in such kind of "slow server" situations. Le me know proper way to resolving such slowness issues and decting the process causing the slowness.

Note - Since ping response was slow, we first suspected network issues. But it was not network issue. We confirmed that by switching the network cable with adjacent server which was also on same subnet.

Comment: To be honest, your machine looks perfectly fine. A load of 1.68 is no problem, your CPU is 95% idle (which is somewhat contradictionary, but the 0.7% wait is fine too). Are you sure it wasn't a **network** problem?

Comment: Seconding atop, it can replace usage of top, iotop, vmstat, etc. For an introduction see http://lwn.net/Articles/387202/

Comment: There is always a chance that something could trigger a bug on the NIC   driver. If that is the case, you should be able to see something standing out in your kernel messages.

Comment: We know which process is causing this slowness.

Comment: We know which process is causing this slowness. I ran strace on that process. 93% of times this process/app tries to open a nonexistent file under nfs and that's causing this slowness. What is peculiar is, it affects the ping response too. There are no packet losses. Though ping response takes average 30ms (as opposed to 0.18ms for other servers on the same subnet). If I kill this process things become normal. As I said, we first suspected network issues. But it was not network issue. We confirmed that by switching the network cable with adjacent server which was also on same subnet.